# Can't find the apex class in scheduled apex

Tags: apex, class, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, jobs

how to find the apex class in this scheduled apex record.its not showing the apex class , then I try this in apex jobs section but it's also not showing.

Please give me solution for that . How do I found that scheduled apex class according to that scheduled job[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SOQL query in Developer Console or Salesforce Inspector Or Any Apex class:

```
SELECT Id, ApexClassId, ApexClass.name, JobType, Status, NumberOfErrors, MethodName FROM AsyncApexJob 
   WHERE JobType in ('BatchApexWorker','ScheduledApex') AND
         CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name = 'scheduled/batch job name'
```